# Dealing with csv sorted by city in Python

Tags: python, csv, data-structures

I have sorted CSV file with weather forecast data:

```
New York
"2016-04-08T07:00Z  6.2 d300    1   0.0 220 10.2    79  331"
"2016-04-08T08:00Z  7.1 d000    1   0.0 223 10.6    74  400"
"2016-04-08T09:00Z  7.7 d000    1   0.0 225 10.9    68  448"
"2016-04-08T10:00Z  8.4 d000    2   0.0 225 10.9    64  553"
"2016-04-08T11:00Z  8.9 d100    5   0.0 226 11.0    59  550"
"2016-04-08T12:00Z  9.1 d100    8   0.0 227 11.0    57  516"
"2016-04-08T13:00Z  8.6 d100    1   0.0 227 10.6    61  447"
"2016-04-08T14:00Z  8.1 d100    4   0.0 227 10.1    64  362"
Boston
"2016-04-08T07:00Z  6.2 d300    1   0.0 220 10.2    79  331"
"2016-04-08T08:00Z  7.1 d000    1   0.0 223 10.6    74  400"
"2016-04-08T09:00Z  7.7 d000    1   0.0 225 10.9    68  448"
"2016-04-08T10:00Z  8.4 d000    2   0.0 225 10.9    64  553"
"2016-04-08T11:00Z  8.9 d100    5   0.0 226 11.0    59  550"
"2016-04-08T12:00Z  9.1 d100    8   0.0 227 11.0    57  516"
"2016-04-08T13:00Z  8.6 d100    1   0.0 227 10.6    61  447"
"2016-04-08T14:00Z  8.1 d100    4   0.0 227 10.1    64  362"
```

etc... each city has 8 weather data entries.

How to deal with this type of CSV in Python?

I would like automatically to map entire CSV to Array of Class instances with attributes like Place, DateTime, Temperature, Attr4, Attr5 etc... or may be to some another data structure - Dictionary?

```
with open('test.csv', 'rb') as csvfile: 
     wreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t', quotechar='"')    
     for row in wreader:
         print row
```

Output of this simple code is

```
['New York']
['2016-04-08T07:00Z\t6.2\td300\t1\t0.0\t220\t10.2\t79\t331']
['2016-04-08T08:00Z\t7.1\td000\t1\t0.0\t223\t10.6\t74\t400']
['2016-04-08T09:00Z\t7.7\td000\t1\t0.0\t225\t10.9\t68\t448']
['2016-04-08T10:00Z\t8.4\td000\t2\t0.0\t225\t10.9\t64\t553']
['2016-04-08T11:00Z\t8.9\td100\t5\t0.0\t226\t11.0\t59\t550']
['2016-04-08T12:00Z\t9.1\td100\t8\t0.0\t227\t11.0\t57\t516']
['2016-04-08T13:00Z\t8.6\td100\t1\t0.0\t227\t10.6\t61\t447']
['2016-04-08T14:00Z\t8.1\td100\t4\t0.0\t227\t10.1\t64\t362']
```

As you see content in double quotes not parsed

Then I changed `quotechar=' '` and that partly solved problem

```
['"2016-04-08T07:00Z', '6.2', 'd300', '1', '0.0', '220', '10.2', '79', '331"']
```

but there still left double quotes . 
How to remove ?

Comment: You should read up on the (easily google-able) [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module!

Comment: have you tried anything? paste what you have achieved and then someone will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditionally read in csv data, capturing city name and appending items into local list. Then, use the list for other extended needs such as defining a class and dictionary.

```
import csv

weatherdata = []
with open('WeatherData.csv'), 'r') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for line in readCSV:
        items = [i.replace('"', '').split() for i in line][0]        
        if len(items) < 3:
            city = items
        else:
            weatherdata.append([' '.join(city)] + items)       

for i in weatherdata:
    print(i)

# ['New York', '2016-04-08T07:00Z', '6.2', 'd300', '1', '0.0', '220', '10.2', '79', '331']
# ['New York', '2016-04-08T08:00Z', '7.1', 'd000', '1', '0.0', '223', '10.6', '74', '400']
# ['New York', '2016-04-08T09:00Z', '7.7', 'd000', '1', '0.0', '225', '10.9', '68', '448']
# ['New York', '2016-04-08T10:00Z', '8.4', 'd000', '2', '0.0', '225', '10.9', '64', '553']
# ['New York', '2016-04-08T11:00Z', '8.9', 'd100', '5', '0.0', '226', '11.0', '59', '550']
# ['New York', '2016-04-08T12:00Z', '9.1', 'd100', '8', '0.0', '227', '11.0', '57', '516']
# ['New York', '2016-04-08T13:00Z', '8.6', 'd100', '1', '0.0', '227', '10.6', '61', '447']
# ['New York', '2016-04-08T14:00Z', '8.1', 'd100', '4', '0.0', '227', '10.1', '64', '362']
# ['Boston', '2016-04-08T07:00Z', '6.2', 'd300', '1', '0.0', '220', '10.2', '79', '331']
# ['Boston', '2016-04-08T08:00Z', '7.1', 'd000', '1', '0.0', '223', '10.6', '74', '400']
# ['Boston', '2016-04-08T09:00Z', '7.7', 'd000', '1', '0.0', '225', '10.9', '68', '448']
# ['Boston', '2016-04-08T10:00Z', '8.4', 'd000', '2', '0.0', '225', '10.9', '64', '553']
# ['Boston', '2016-04-08T11:00Z', '8.9', 'd100', '5', '0.0', '226', '11.0', '59', '550']
# ['Boston', '2016-04-08T12:00Z', '9.1', 'd100', '8', '0.0', '227', '11.0', '57', '516']
# ['Boston', '2016-04-08T13:00Z', '8.6', 'd100', '1', '0.0', '227', '10.6', '61', '447']
# ['Boston', '2016-04-08T14:00Z', '8.1', 'd100', '4', '0.0', '227', '10.1', '64', '362']
```

Comment: line[0] data is ['2016-04-08T07:00Z\t6.2\td300\t1\t0.0\t220\t10.2\t79\t331'] so line[1] is out of range

Comment: See updated code which handles the quotation structure using a list comprehension and list split (even handling the space in city like *New York*).

Answer (score 0):

So if I got it right quotechar=' ' solved problem. Then result is

```
['"2016-04-08T07:00Z', '6.2', 'd300', '1', '0.0', '220', '10.2', '79', '331"']
['"2016-04-08T08:00Z', '7.1', 'd000', '1', '0.0', '223', '10.6', '74', '400"']
['"2016-04-08T09:00Z', '7.7', 'd000', '1', '0.0', '225', '10.9', '68', '448"']
['"2016-04-08T10:00Z', '8.4', 'd000', '2', '0.0', '225', '10.9', '64', '553"']
['"2016-04-08T11:00Z', '8.9', 'd100', '5', '0.0', '226', '11.0', '59', '550"']
['"2016-04-08T12:00Z', '9.1', 'd100', '8', '0.0', '227', '11.0', '57', '516"']
['"2016-04-08T13:00Z', '8.6', 'd100', '1', '0.0', '227', '10.6', '61', '447"']
```

and in total

```
weatherdata  = []
with open('test.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t', quotechar=' ')
    for line in readCSV:
        if len(line) == 1:
            city = line[0]
        else:            
            weatherdata.append([city] + line)

for c in weatherdata:
    print(c)
```

Comment: Nonono.... there is still problem with double quotes  ['"2016-04-08T07:00Z'..................'79', '331"'